# Reading a huge csv file and converting to JSON with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, stream

I am trying to read a csv file with many columns. And the first row is always the header for the csv file. I would like to convert the csv data into JSON. I can read it as String and convert into JSON but I am not able to assign headers to it.

For example input csv looks like:

```
first_name,last_name
A,A1
B,B1
C,C1

Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("sample.csv"))
List<String[]> readall = stream.map(l -> l.split(",")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
List<String> test1 = readall.stream().skip(0).map(row -> row[1]).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And using com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper's WriteValueAsString only creates JSON with no header.

I would like the output in the format like

```
{
[{"first_name":"A","last_name":"A1"},{"first_name":"B"....
```

How do I use stream in Java to prepare this JSON format?

Please help.

Comment: IMO, you shall first declare a custom `Object` including those fields to start off with and then write a simple `for` loop iteration to map the stream of strings and then look for the stream way of doing it.

Comment: I don't know the field names earlier. CSV header will only carry the field names which I could use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd tackle this problem in two steps: first, read the headers, then, read the rest of the lines:

```
static String[] headers(String path) throws IOException {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        return br.readLine().split(",");
    }
}
```

Now, you can use the method above as follows:

```
String path = "sample.csv";

// Read headers
String[] headers = headers(path);

List<Map<String, String>> result = null;

// Read data
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
    result = stream
        .skip(1) // skip headers
        .map(line -> line.split(","))
        .map(data -> {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
               map.put(headers[i], data[i]);
            }
            return map;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You can change the `for` loop inside the 2nd `map` operation:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
    result = stream
        .skip(1) // skip headers
        .map(line -> line.split(","))
        .map(data -> IntStream.range(0, data.length)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> headers[i], i -> data[i])))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**EDIT:** If instead of collecting to a list, you want to perform an action for the maps read from each line, you can do it as follows:

```
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
    stream
        .skip(1) // skip headers
        .map(line -> line.split(","))
        .map(data -> IntStream.range(0, data.length)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> headers[i], i -> data[i])))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

(Here the action is to print each map).

This version can be improved, i.e. it boxes the stream of `int`s and then unboxes each `int` again to use it as the index of the `headers` and `data` arrays. Also, readability can be improved by extracting the creation of each map to a private method.

Notes: Maybe reading the file twice is not the best approach performance-wise, but the code is simple and expressive. Apart from this, `null` handling, data transformation (i.e. to numbers or dates, etc) and border cases (i.e. no headers, no data lines or different lengths for the arrays of data, etc) are left as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: Great. Thank you. Here we are collecting it as a list. Is there a way I can emit (say even print) one line at a time in JSON format?

Comment: @passionate sure, use `forEach(System.out::println)` instead of `collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to do

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {

        Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("src/main/resources/test1.csv"));
        List<Map<String, Object>> readall = stream.map(l -> {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            String[] values = l.split(",");

            map.put("name", values[0]);
            map.put("age", values[1]);

            return map;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        ObjectMapper mapperObj = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonResp = mapperObj.writeValueAsString(readall);
        System.out.println(jsonResp);

    }
}
```

Works with Java -8 Streams, with headers, and uses jackson to convert it into json. used CSV

```
abc,20
bbc,30
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple,
Don't convert it into List of Strings. Convert it into List of HashMaps and then use org.json library to convert it into json . Use jackson to convert the CSV to Hashmap

Let the input stream be

```
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("filename.csv"));
```

Example: 
To convert CSV to HashMap

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> read(InputStream stream) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {
 List<Map<String, Object>> response = new LinkedList<Map<String, Object>>();
 CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
 CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();
 MappingIterator<Map<String, String>> iterator = mapper.reader(Map.class).with(schema).readValues(stream);
 while (iterator.hasNext()) 
 {
       response.add(Collections.<String, Object>unmodifiableMap(iterator.next()));
 }
 return response;
 }
```

To convert List of Map to Json

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());
```

Comment: Is there a way I could use Java 8's stream API? The older methods are not able to read huge files and it often results in error.

Comment: Just clear me something. Since the CSV file is huge, you are trying to stream that data to consume less memory by JVM. right?

Comment: If that is the case, even after you stream the CSV file and convert it to a list of objects ( In your example ), all the data is loaded into your JVM memory. In the above method also the same thing happens. So just using streams doesn't improve your performance. The way you design the approach will only improve performance and work with optimal memory.

Comment: Not to consume less memory. But the bigger files don't work and often only fail with older methods. It works really fast with Java 8 stream API